# Length of character should not cross 4000 in apex validation

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an item :p1_name in apex, here we can enter only 4000 character, if the limit crossed then the error should trigger from validation that the limit exceeds 4000.

here i have used the below code in validation but its not working.

```
if length(P95_SLACK_ADHOC_USER_REQUEST)>4000 then
   return false;
else
   return true;
end if;
```

But its not working

Answer (score 2):

If this is code you used, then item name lacks in colon, i.e. should be

```
:P95_SLACK_ADHOC_USER_REQUEST
```